# Operator overloading(exceptions)

Tags: operator-overloading, operator-keyword

In C++, what are the operators which cannot be overloaded and why? Explain the reason for each. I would like to know exactly why we cannot overload these operators (.),(.*),(::),(?:) and sizeof.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you please tell how you were planning to use `sizeof` operator if it would be possible to overload it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most straightforward answer would be because it is a bad idea. All operators that you listed have a specific meaning in C++.

You can get a detailed answer from people who is working on C++ standard or compiler developers.

You can get a list of all operators that cannot be overloaded from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).